# Using a text box to return a value

Tags: ms-access-2010

I would like to return the value from a control which is coming from a table of which it's field is linked to another table.

The control which i would like to install will be inserted on the mail form 'frmValueChain16' but will source the control 'contact' which is a control located on sub form 'frmValueChain16' and is directly linked to a multiple table query that i built to feed the subform.

My text box instead of returning the text value of the name of the contact (the field which i am trying to call) is returning the contact's unique ID number.

Below is what i have so far.

```
=[frmValueChain16].[Form]([contact].[Text])
```

Comment: Need specifics. You have a form named 'frmValueChain16' that has a textbox control named _____? Your form has a recordsource that is based on what table? You have a textbox named _____? that is bound to field _____? in recordsource?

Comment: I'm afraid I don't understand. You say you have a "mail form 'frmValueChain16'", but then say "located on sub form 'frmValueChain16'". Do you really have a subform embedded into some other MAIN form? The syntax to reference a field found on a subform (assuming you place this code in the MAIN form) is like: Msgbox "My subform contains: " & Forms![MyMainForm]!MySub.Form.MyTextField   Note that 'MySub' is the name of the CONTROL on the MAIN form - it is NOT the actual name of the other form.